# Superset - Unable to import database using SQLAlchemy. Library not loaded error

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-3.6

I am running Apache superset on my localhost. However, when I create a database by using SQLAlchemy URI, superset throws the following error:

> ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!\n\nThe error message returned was:\ndlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so\n  Reason: image not found"}

I have made the following symlinks in my /usr/local/lib. my python3 resides in /usr/local/bin/python3

- 1. _mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so -> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
- 2. MySQLdb -> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb
- 3. libmysqlclient.21.dylib -> /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib

Do I have to create some kind of symlink for libssl.1.0.0.dylib?

Following is the .bash_profile paths:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I need to import my database to superset but I am stuck here.

Comment: Can you try setting up Superset inside an Environment. I think that will solve the issues that you are facing now.

Comment: @NikhilBaby I tried to run the server in a virtual env, still the same issue